# Import/Export of survey definition

Tags: surveymonkey

Is there an API to import or export an entire survey definition by survey ID?  The definition would include the question text, question kind, and possible answers depending on the type of question.  I'm not talking about specific responses or a summary of responses, but rather information about the survey itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a complete API to export all the survey data (as much or as little as you please). The output will be in the JSON format.

In your case, the way it works is you first download a list of survey IDs ([get_survey_list](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/mashery/get_survey_list)). Note that these are not the same as the survey code that is part of the web address you've sent to respondents. After you have retrieved the survey IDs, you can retrieve survey details ([get_survey_details](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/mashery/get_survey_details)) by passing the API the survey ID.

You have to register on the [developer site](https://developer.surveymonkey.com) and also request an API key and authentication token. This can all be done in the browser if you aren't familiar with programming.

You can also download from the API from a browser using the [API Console](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/io-docs).

If you are comfortable with python, or want to learn, you can find some pre-programmed stuff here: https://github.com/SurveyMonkey/python_guides

You can also use [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) to access the survey data.

Comment: In any way you might want to be careful as survey monkey API developer T&C state that 'Apps which facilitate the exporting of API Content for importation into a SurveyMonkey competitor’s product or service.' are not allowed. That's what you get if you are using a propietary service :-(

Answer (score 1):

Accoording to API Guide, you could use this:

https://developer.surveymonkey.com/mashery/get_survey_details